# Ruby - alias for object class

Tags: ruby, class, object, alias

sorry for my english.

My code ...

```
class MyClass

  NewFood = Food

  def index
    @items = NewFood.all
  end
end
```

`@items.first` is a Food object, but I want to get a NewFood object

Some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this example:

```
class Foo
  @@instances = []

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
    @@instances << self
  end

  def self.all
    @@instances
  end
end

class Bar
  NewFoo = Foo.dup

  def index
    @items = NewFoo.all
  end
end

# Now Bar::NewFoo will instantiate it's own objects
Bar::NewFoo.new(5)
Bar::NewFoo.new('fish')
Bar.new.index
=>  [#<Bar::NewFoo:0x00000002f33cf0 @value=5>,
     #<Bar::NewFoo:0x00000002f65958 @value="fish">]
```

However I fail to see the need for this kind of metaprogramming hack.
**Edit:** crap, I forgot class variables (`@@var`) are shared along it's childs, so this example could turn messy.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to say you want a `NewFood` object.  There are only two classes: `MyClass` and `Food`.  The constant `MyClass::NewFood` just points to `Food`; just because you defined that constant doesn't mean you can expect the instances of the `Food` class to start behaving differently and saying that their class is `NewFood`.

Could you zoom out and tell us what the big picture is?  What are you trying to accomplish?  What real life problem are you trying to solve?  We can probably offer a better way of solving it.